# AddStock' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

   this.Hide();
   AddStock as = new AddStock();    
}
```

here is error
please tell me how to solve it.

Comment: `as` is a keyword, name it differently, or name it `@as`, if you really want to call it like that

Answer (score 0):

`as` is not allowed as name for a variable, because it´s a keywors used in C#. you´d better be off by use another name, e.g. ÀddStock`.

If you *really* need/want to use that name use the `@` in front:

```
AddStock @as = new AddStock();
```

But then you´d have to add that operator whenever you´re using that variable, e.g. the following would cause a compiler-error:

```
as.DoSometing();
```

whereas this won´t:

```
@as.DoSomething();
```

Comment: Maybe add what the keyword actually [does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx)? :)

Comment: Error 1 'PL.AddStock' does not contain a definition for 'show' and no extension method 'show' accepting a first argument of type 'PL.AddStock' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Rizwan\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\PL\PL\AdminPanel.xaml.cs 43

Comment: From your current code it is impossible to guess what `Show` is, so you have to provide far more information. However this goes far beyond the scope of this question. You should therefor create a new question and also consider to accept this answer if it answered that particular question (which from my point of view it does).